# What does a line beginning with a dot mean?

Tags: javascript

I was reading through the [Crafty tutorial](http://craftyjs.com/tutorial/bananabomber/create-a-game) and came across a code snippet that I can't find documentation for. It is so hard to search for punctuation.

The lines in question, 11 and 12, follow the `Crafty.e` line and begin with `.text` and `.css`. What object do those properties belong to?

```
//the loading screen that will display while our assets load
Crafty.scene("loading", function () {
    //load takes an array of assets and a callback when complete
    Crafty.load(["sprite.png"], function () {
        Crafty.scene("main"); //when everything is loaded, run the main scene
    });

    //black background with some loading text
    Crafty.background("#000");
    Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 })
            .text("Loading")
            .css({ "text-align": "center" });
});

//automatically play the loading scene
Crafty.scene("loading");
```

Where would this be in the specification?

Comment: Lol - lots of quick answers.

Comment: Its called fluent interface, if you familiar with php there are several ORM frameworks which use it.

Comment: Thank you all for the great explanations. I feel foolish now. Of course a dot is an operator and therefore can have whitespace surrounding it.

Comment: @JeffStrunk No need to feel foolish - this type of thing happens to all of us at one time or another, and even several times throughout our lives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A line starting with a `.` is simply a function/property being called on the *previous* function/line's object.

---

In your specific case,

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 })
      .text("Loading")
      .css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

`.text("Loading")` is just a function call on the result of `Crafty.e(...)`.

Similarly, `.css({ "text-align": "center" })` is simply a function call on the result of the previous line's `.text("Loading")`.

Because it's in the same line, the `.attr(...)` call isn't outwardly visible, but it is the exact same things as the others in their own lines.

---

In *expanded* terms, the sample above is the same as doing this:

```
var eResult = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text");
var attrResult = eResult.attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 });
var textResult = attrResult.text("Loading");
var cssResult = textResult.css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

---

As others have stated, this is simply a method of *chaining* calls to the same object - however, be aware(!) that this isn't always possible in all programming languages. jQuery and many other JavaScript framework/libraries have taken this approach to make development easier/smoother, therefore, it is widespread in JavaScript development.

In JavaScript specifically, the **real** statement termination is a `;` (semicolon). What this means is that a *single* statement can span several lines.

Answer (score 4):

The author of this code is probably just trying to make it more readable. The `.` at the beginning of the line simply continues the previous line.

So this...

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 })
            .text("Loading")
            .css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

...is the same as having it all on one line:

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 }).text("Loading").css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

The semi-colon at the end of the line terminates the statement.

However, by writing it the way the author did, it is easier to see that you're taking the results from the `attr` function and feeding it into the `text` function, and those results finally into the `css` function. Well...easier **for me** to read anyway. Readability can be very subjective.

This is called function chaining, and is described with some examples in [this blog post](http://css.dzone.com/news/javascript-chaining-your-metho).

Answer (score 2):

It's just a continuation of the previous line. In one line, it's:

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 }).text("Loading").css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

It's called "Chaining", where the previous function invocation returns an interface (usually an object) that contains functions. Instead of storing them intermediately or calling them one by one, you just "chain" the next call since the previous invocation is as good as what it returned.

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text")
      .attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 })
      .text("Loading") 
      .css({ "text-align": "center" });

//synonymous to

var eReturn = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text");
var aReturn = eReturn.attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 });
var tReturn = aReturn.text("Loading");

tReturn.css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

Answer (score 2):

They're basically continuations of the previous lines.
So lines 11 and 12 are essentially the same as:
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 }).text("Loading").css({ "text-align": "center" });

The text method is being applied to the result of the .atr function.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to these previous answers - your specific question was "where is this in the API?" If you look at the method signatures in the API, you will see that each of these methods returns a reference to 'this'.  E.g. :

```
public this .attr(String property, * value)
```

Therefore, you can "chain" together calls (as other commenters have suggested) because the object reference is being returned. E.g.

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text").attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 }).text("Loading").css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

is the same as

```
var myEntity = Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Text");
myEntity.attr({ w: 100, h: 20, x: 150, y: 120 });
myEntity.text("Loading");
myEntity.css({ "text-align": "center" });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically chaining methods. Read more [here](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/04/javascript-method-chaining.html)

It's only listed as a new line to be more clearer, but you're basically just calling those methods one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

those are not new lines of code they are a continuation of "Crafty.e"